# A variation of longest paths in directed acyclic graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms

> Let $D=(V,A)$ be a simple directed acyclic graph, where $A$ is a set of arcs. Let $S$ be a subset of $\{(u,v)| \text{there is a directed path from $u$ to $v$}\}$. The *$S$-length* of a path $P$ is defined to be the number of elements of $S$ contained in $P$, here $(u,v)\in S$ is said to be contained in $P$ if $u,v \in V(P)$. For example, if $S =\{(u,v)| \text{there is a directed path from $u$ to $v$}\}$, then length of a path $P$ is ${L(P)}\choose{2}$ where $L(P)$ is the length of the path $P$. My question is to find *a path of longest $S$-length* in $D$. Is there a polynomial algorithm to solve it? If it is NP-hard, then is there a good approximation algorithm?

I am so sorry I realized there is a mistake in my old question. Here $S$ is a subset of $V\times V$,i.e, a subset of all pairs of vertices, but $S$ is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: Small nitpick: '(NP-hard)' is not known to be the the negation of '$\exists$polynomial algorithm'. The phrasing of the OP, with the "Or, if" makes it sound a bit as it it was. I would recommed to replace "Or, if it..." with simply "If it...". I shied away from making this invasive edit.

Comment: Dear Peter, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Do binary search on powers of the adjacency matrix.

Comment: @Ethan Is there polynomial or exponential number of maximal path in DAG?

Comment: @Moshe I misinterpreted your problem, discount what I previously said.

Comment: If, as you say, "$S$ is a subset of $V\times V$", then it is simply *wrong* to write, as you do, "Let $S$ be a subset of $\{\{u,v\}\mid\text{there is a directed path from $u$ to $v$}$." In usual ZF set theory, it must be '$\{ (u,v) \mid\text{there is a directed path from $u$ to $v$}$.' instead. Note that $\{u,v\}$ is never equal to $(u,v)$, and this can be *proved* from the axioms of ZF, this is not a notational convention. Would you please revise the question text?

Comment: Re "Is there polynomial or exponential number of maximal path in DAG?": you presumably mean the maximum, and then the answer is *obviously exponential*. It is obviously possible to have $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ distinct maximal directed paths in an acyclic digraph on $n$ vertices. (And this bound can be much improved.) I hesitate to describe one example in detail, because the examples are so abundant; one is: take triangles pasted at their vertices along a path, and orient them all in the direction of the path; then you'll have $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ independent binary choices to build a maximal path.

Answer (score 2):

It’s NP-hard to approximate this within any constant factor, by a reduction from 2-CSP (that it is hard to approximate 2-CSP follows from the PCP theorem and parallel repetition). Suppose I have an instance of 2-CSP with variables $x_1, ..., x_n$ taking values in the alphabet $\Sigma$, and constraints $C_{i,j} \subseteq \Sigma \times \Sigma$ for certain pairs $i,j$ between $1$ and $n$. Make a directed graph $(V, A)$ with $V = \{v_{i,a} : i \le n, a \in \Sigma\}$ and $A = \{(v_{i,a}, v_{i+1,b}) : i \le n-1, a,b \in \Sigma\}$. For each constraint $C_{i,j}$ (assuming $i$ less than $j$ without loss of generality), we include the pairs $(v_{i,a},v_{j,b})$ such that $(a,b) \in C_{i,j}$ in the set $S$. Then any maximal path corresponds to an assignment of the variables to elements of $\Sigma$, and the $S$-length is equal to the number of satisfied constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia page on longest path problems gives an efficient algorithm to find longest paths in directed acyclic graphs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

If you adapt this algorithm by weighting arcs 1 if they lie in S, and 0 otherwise, this gives the algorithm you want.

Comment: Dear Simon, thank you for your answer. There is a mistake in my previous question and I have just changed it. I am really sorry!